# Increasing database field by specified percentage

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have product information stored in a MySQL database. The "price" column in the database just contains the numeric price.

I need to write a function in PHP that can go through those values and increase them by a specified percentage, but am not really sure the proper way to go about it. Is there a function in MySQL that can do it, or do the prices need to be read from the database, modified, and written back to the database?

Comment: you're trying to modify the price?

Comment: Yes. I need it increased by a certain percentage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The appropriate SQL is:

```
update t
    set price = price * (1 + $percentage / 100);
```

Comment: I will be able to test this out in a little bit. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: well above query will update the required data depending on percentage but I don't think there is any need to add 1 as this is not in requirement.

Comment: @Exception . . The percentage is presumably a value such as "10".  To increase by 10%, you need to multiply by 1.1 (which is 1 + $percentage / 10).  That is what is means to *increase* something.

Comment: Is there a way using MySQL functions to round up or down to the nearest whole number?

Comment: And I can put a WHERE condition at the end like any other MySQL query?

Comment: Worked fine. Thank you :)

Comment: @SherwinFlight . . . The function `round()` does that.